# "No proximity sensor found" error on Surface Go 2

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, nfc, proximity

I tried to read NFC MIFARE cards from an UWP C# App on a Micrsoft Surface Go 2. But even with the [Sample App "ProximitySensor" by Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ProximitySensor) I did not get it to work. The sample app kept telling me "No proximity sensor found".

Comment: Hi, I'm not seeing a question here.
If all you're doing is sharing your experience (which is great don't get me wrong, it's just that you are not expecting any answers), you should pose the problem in the question, then answer your own question (by checking the Answer your own question box when creating your question)

Comment: You have a SMART Card which looks like Disk Mounted to your machine. You need a window drive to be able to access the card and you need to unlock the card because it is encrypted.  When debugging a Smart Card I usually due following 1) Read Card with a File Explorer.  This makes sure the driver is installed and the card can be unlock. 2) Develop c# application by first unlocking card with File Explorer before starting c# application.  Determine address size and data sizes.  Data/Address could be 8,16,32 bits 3) Get unlock working with c#. You can't unlock card until you first determine sizes.

Comment: I use NFC reader in my project. But, I use use dll for connect to reader. Given that there are sample codes, you should not have a problem. After install driver, You can connect to reader.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things necessary to get this solved.

The first one is, to have the right version of the Surface Go 2. The first one I got, was the "Consumer" version (so far I did not know, there is another one out there). This one does **not** have an NFC reader built in at all (or at least no driver to make it working).

What you need is a [Surface Go 2 **for Business**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/surface-go-2-for-business/8wzd6dhzj7kv?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab). Only this one has an NFC sensor built in and registered in the devices.

Opening up the Device Manager on this one, it showed me a "Proximity Device" (an NXP something...).

However, trying the sample app, I still got "No proximity sensor found". It turns out the Windows API has two different classes for accessing NFC (they call it proximity) devices.

The first one is the [`ProximitySensor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Sensors.ProximitySensor?view=winrt-19041) class, which was used in the Sample app and did **not** work on the Surface Go 2.

The other one is [`ProximityDevice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Networking.Proximity.ProximityDevice?view=winrt-19041), which is part of the *Networking* Namespace. This one is working on the Surface Go 2.

Here's some [sample code](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-microsoft/tree/master/Official%20Windows%20Platform%20Sample/Proximity%20sample) to use it, which read the content of my MIFARE card just fine.